# Multiple indexes or multiple shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of document storage machines 1..N, which all store documents with identical schema (i.e. all with a single elasticsearch mapping),  I'm not sure how to implement the elasticsearch index for the complete content to cope with this use case:

A machine K's content has changed and needs to be completely reindexed without affecting the rest of the index (i.e. the documents held on the other machines).

Do I

- Create a single index and N shards, use routing to control the
  shard each storage machine uses, then when a store K needs to be
  reindexed, delete and index the corresponding shard

or

- Create multiple indexes with the same mapping,  myindex/1 ..
  myindex/N, and make sure each store K only talks to myindex/K

The problem I'm having with the first option, which feels more correct, is that I don't really understand routing:  I believe the routing is just a hash so I can't just use "K" for the routing and get shard K - I get shard hash(K)).  Which means I can't guarantee that shard K contains **all** and **only** the documents for store K.

Answer (score 0):

The first option I think. Each document is stored on a primary shard, that's why Es needs to know which this is. That's the idea of dividing your big index.

See this link with formula and explanation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html